# Special characters in XML attributes with NSXMLParser

Tags: ios, xml, api, nsxmlparser

I get something like the following from a third party API:

```
<el attr="test.

another test." />
```

I use `NSXMLParser` to read the file into my app.

However, in the delegate, the attribute gets converted to `test.  another test.` Obviously I'd like to see it with the line breaks intact.

I initially assumed that this was a bug but, according to the XML Spec it's doing the right thing:

> a whitespace character (#x20, #xD, #xA, #x9) is processed by
>   appending #x20 to the normalized value

([See section 3.3.3.](http://www.xml.com/axml/testaxml.htm))

What are my options? Note that it's a third party API so I can't change it, even though it's wrong.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you're looking for a non-spec-compliant parser? You might want to see if [libxml2](http://xmlsoft.org/) can possibly already give you access to the "raw" attribute, though I kind of doubt it. Your only other choice is to hack up your own non-spec-compliant parser (which, btw, you really shouldn't do unless you have literally no other option).

Comment: Yeah, that was pretty much my conclusion. I was hoping that I was wrong :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSData *xmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"url://"]];
NSMutableString *myXmlStr = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithData:xmlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSRange range = [myXmlStr rangeOfString:@"\n"];
[myXmlStr replaceCharactersInRange:range withString:@"[:newline:]"];
NSData *newXmlData = [myXmlStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Just replace [:newline:] with new line character whenever u like it :)

Comment: An excellent idea! But incase there's more than one newline character he should probably use `NSString *newXmlString = [myXmlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@"<#Return Was Here Key#>"]`. But really, good idea.